# PHP at the end of every line append a line from another text

Tags: php

I have two text files. First one contains:

```
1,
1,
1,
1,
```

The second one contains:

```
3,4,5,
6,7,8,
0,8,9,
12,4,6,
```

And what I would like to get as an output is:

```
1,3,4,5,
1,6,7,8,
1,0,8,9,
1,12,4,6,
```

Basically to append at the end of every line of the first text file a line from the second text file with PHP.

```
$handle = fopen("data/data1.txt", "r");

      //what needs to be appended
      $fileContents = file_get_contents('output.txt');
      $fixedFileContents = preg_replace('/.+/', '$0$handle', $fileContents);
      file_put_contents($fixedFileContents, 'output.txt.txt');
```

The code is completely wrong... Thank you in advance!

Comment: `file_put_contents($fixedFileContents, 'output.txt.txt');`  needs to be `file_put_contents('output.txt.txt',$fixedFileContents);` (file name/path  needs to come first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

```
$first_page_array = file("data/data1.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$second_page_array = file("provide second file path",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$final_array = [];

foreach($first_page_array as $key=>$first_page){
   $final_array[] = $first_page.','.$second_page_array[$key];
}
print_r( $final_array);

file_put_contents('output.txt.txt',$final_array);
```